# Largest practical datasets in Google spreadsheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking into using google sheets as some sort of aggregation solution for different data sources. It's reasonably easy to configure those data sources to output to a common google sheets and it's need to online for sharing. This sheet would act as my raw, un-treated data source. I would then have some dashboards/sub-tables based on that data.

Now, early tests seem to show I'm going to have to be careful about efficiency as it seems I'm pushing against the maximum 2 millions cells for spreadsheets (we're talking about 15-20k rows of data & 100 or so columns). Handling the data also seems to be pretty slow (regardless of cells limits), at least using formulas, even considering using arrays & avoiding vlookups etc...

My plan would be to create other documents (separate documents, not just adding tabs) & refer to the source data through import-range & using spreadsheet-key. Those would be using subsets of the data only required for each dashboards. This should allow me to create dashboard that would run faster than if setup directly off my big raw data file, or at least that's my thinking.

Am I embarking on a fool's errand here? Anyone has been looking into similarly large dataset on google docs? Basically trying to see if what I have in mind is even practical or not... If you have better ideas in terms of architecture please do share...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue once.

Using a multi layer approach like the one you suggested is indeed one method to work around this.
The spreadsheets themselves have no problem storing those two million cells, it's the displaying of all the data that is problematic, so accessing it via Import or scripts can be worthwhile.

Some other things I would consider:

How up to date does the data need to be? Import range is slow and can make the dashboard you create sluggish, maybe a scheduled import with the aggregation happening in Google Apps Script is a viable option.

At that point you might even want to consider using BigQuery for the data storage (and aggregation), whether you pull the data from another spreadsheet in this project or a database that will not run into any issues once you exceed 2 million elements would be future proof.

Alternatively you can use [fusion tables](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/fusion-tables)* for the storage which are drive based , although I think you cannot run sophisticated SQL queries on it.

---

*: You probably need to enable them in Drive via right click > more > Connect more apps

Comment: Didn't know Bigquery had an (apparently) pretty simple integration with sheets now. Reluctant to use that because once I'm done not sure someone can manage things with that setup, but they could manage some system based on sheets... Keep that in mind though.

 Fusion tables are an interesting idea as well. To be seen if I can query them well enough for my use case....

Overall somewhat encouraging...